# SUMPRODUCT with multiple criteria that have multiple variables

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Background: 16 men in different colors of jackets are having a party, some of them sharing same first names. In the actual sheet there will be thousands of rows. A much-simplified example:

```
    A           B                   C
1   First Names Color of jackets    Shape of Face
2   John        yellow              round
3   Alan        purple              round
4   Sam         red                 round
5   Tom         blue                oblong
6   John        blue                oblong
7   Tom         yellow              oblong
8   Tom         yellow              oblong
9   Sam         red                 oblong
10  Alan        red                 oblong
11  Timothy     blue                diamond
12  Sam         purple              diamond
13  Sam         red                 diamond
14  Alan        red                 diamond
15  Timothy     red                 diamond
16  John        blue                triangle
17  Timothy     blue                triangle
```

What I need to do is count unique values in certain categories (sometimes in multiple categories, AND or OR). For instance, I now need to count the number of different names of round-faced men in yellow jackets.  Fortunately, there is a formula that works in this situation. To count `round`-faced men in `yellow` jackets you can use this where D1 = Yellow and E1 = Round:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B17=D1)*(C2:C17=E1))/COUNTIFS(A2:A17,A2:A17&"",B2:B17,B2:B17&"",C2:C17,C2:C17&""))
```

It is when I take the problem one step further that I have trouble.  I want to count the number of different names of `round`-faced or `oblong`-faced men in `yellow` jackets or `red` jackets or `blue` jackets. The answer in this case would be `4`.  Here is what I initially wrote in my situation. For this example, D1 = Yellow, D2 = Red, and D3 = Blue. E1 = Round, E2 = Oblong.

This gave me an `#N/A` error. However, when I took out the third variable, D3, so the equation looked like the one below it gave me an accurate number:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B17={D1,D2})*(C2:C17=E1,E2}))/COUNTIFS(A2:A17,A2:A17&"",B2:B17,B2:B17&"",C2:C17,C2:C17&""))
```

Unfortunately, when I did it a few more times in different scenarios it began to give me numbers that were not accurate.

How to count unique values among duplicates using multiple criteria when each criteria may have multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with counts of unique values, the reciprocal `SUMPRODUCT`/`COUNTIF(S)` construction is not only difficult to construct beyond a few criteria but also - perhaps surprisingly - incredibly inefficient compared to the alternative `FREQUENCY`/`MATCH` set-up, especially over large datasets.

With **CSE****:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B17,D1:D3,0)),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2:C17,E1:E2,0)),MATCH(A2:A17,A2:A17,0))),ROW(A2:A17)-MIN(ROW(A2:A17))+1),1))`

I say surprising as the natural assumption might be that a combination of `FREQUENCY` and `MATCH` using an exact *match_type* parameter would be pretty inefficient. In fact, it turns out to be quite the opposite.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thank you for the assistance @XOR LX. The example I used in my question was similar but not exact to the data I have so I'm still having issues. Here is a small sample of the exact data I'm working with. I don't have enough room to put it all in this comment so please see the one below. In this scenario I would like to know the count of unique customers that got a renewal or upgrade from the following regions: usd, cad, mex. The data itself is exported from a database and I am trying to keep things simple so I would like to use the variables (e.g. usd, renewal) in the formula.

Comment: OK, I can not get this formatted properly so it can be read. Hopefully, my description will be enough. I am doing a unique count of customer ids (e.g. 2342, 3423).  This would be column A. I am trying to count them for different scenarios e.g. renewal and upgrade. This would be column B. Breaking it down even further would be country type. This would be column C. Here is what I would want Excel to tell me. Give me a count of unique customer ids that were either renewals or upgrades and were from usd or cad or mex. The data comes from a database so I would need to refer to variables by name.

Comment: So just adapt my formula accordingly. If your values are not in contiguous cells then you can enter them as static arrays within the formula, e.g. {"usd","cad",max"} within an ISNUMBER(MATCH construction, as per my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a PivotTable:

[image: SO33179194 example]

The formula in B20 is:

```
=COUNT(F3:G5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the bigger picture I need to take the results of several sheets of several formulas and have it calculated to a summary page. In this scenario a pivot table does not work.